# Android: Buttons Orientation for different screen sizes

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I have problems with my buttons layout.

I made the "small, normal, large, xlarge" layout folders.

But still at some devices the buttons got mixed together !

When i view my layout using the devices set  eclipse i can see the problem but i can't know what is the dimensions of the device.

My Question is: can anyone give me the dimensions of each one of these devices or who can i make a layout for each one?

the devices in the image blew

[image: http://goo.gl/bss3Ot]

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainnati"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >


>
        <Button

        android:id="@+id/b_info"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@drawable/info" />



    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_pass"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/b_comp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/b_comp"
        android:layout_marginTop="350dp"
        android:background="@drawable/pass" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Post your layout file.

Comment: I added the layout file, i use a lot of Hard coding i know!. but the blame goes to the one who teach me this way.. and i have to finish the project as soon as possible.

Comment: Two things: I see two buttons. The second is below and aligned to the left of one that doesn't exist in your code (b_comp). So, I guess it should refer to **b_info**, instead

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "buttons got mixed together"? Also, you talk about several ("small, normal, large, xlarge") layout folders, yet only show one layout XML. Do you really need 4 different layouts? (That's probably a bad idea.) For a start, try reading [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) thoughtfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things: I see two Buttons.
The second is below and aligned to the left of one that doesn't exist in your code (b_comp).
So, I guess it should refer to **b_info**, instead.

And, instead of centerVertical, I'd set centerInParent (which also centers horizontally) for the first Button (b_info).
I'd use centerHorizontal for the lower Button, instead of alignLeft.

So, after all, my layout file would be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainnati"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >
    >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_info"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/info" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/b_pass"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/b_info"
        android:background="@drawable/pass" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you sir, your edit helped me a lot!
Now it work like a charm, can you please explain what was wrong with my work?
- I've read the link you gave before !
- sorry about the (b_comp) it was a copy/paste mistake.
- i made the 4 layout folders to make the layout work with different screens, so the system will chose the layout suitable for the current screen.
Thanks again.

Comment: Glad that it worked. You need to read more in deep how a RelativeLayout works. You also don't have to be sorry. Errors happen. I also think you don't have to make 4 distinct layout. Just give "wrap content" for width and height of your buttons. Obviously, yoou have to provide 4 different versions of your images, at the resolutions (in dpi) you want to support. That's all.